# What does the dot (.) in a command mean?

Tags: bash

Here is a command that I saw in a tutorial:

```
mkswap /swap && chown root. /swap && chmod 0600 /swap && swapon /swap
```

What does the `.` mean?

Comment: Wow you guys are awesome.. theres still so much stuff I dont know in linux bash commandlin'ing :) Thank you all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.` in this context is a deprecated form of `:` and is a separator between the new owner and group.

From `info chown`:

> ```
>    Some older scripts may still use ‘.’ in place of the ‘:’ separator.
> POSIX 1003.1-2001 (*note Standards conformance::) does not require
> support for that, but for backward compatibility GNU ‘chown’ supports
> ‘.’ so long as no ambiguity results.  New scripts should avoid the use
> of ‘.’ because it is not portable, and because it has undesirable
> results if the entire OWNER‘.’GROUP happens to identify a user whose
> name contains ‘.’.
> ```

So in this context it's the same as `chown root: /swap`, which in turn means

```
OWNER:
     If a colon but no group name follows OWNER, that user is made the
     owner of the files and the group of the files is changed to OWNER’s
     login group.
```

Since root's login group is `root`, it's equivalent to `chown root:root /swap`

Comment: Grrr!  I was just writing my answer and you beat me to it.  +1 =)

Answer (score 5):

It is a shortened version of

```
sudo chown root:root /swap
```

as it will set the group to the same as the username.

Try creating a folder, then set the ownership to root that same way, then when completed, try setting the ownership to your username.

```
sudo chown $USER. folder/
```

Hope this help!